# Symfony 6 setting a boolean value to false in the databse (i'm using pgadmin4)

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

first i set the value to false like this :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJSVi.png)
and then i set the getter and setter :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjL88.png)
finally when i use the make migration and migration migrate it give me this error :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5q9b.png)
knowing that the migration is :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYQTp.png)

i just want to make the is_verifed column in the database as false for a default value .

Comment: change typehint from ?bool to bool.

?type means null|type

Comment: Please post code and not screenshots

Answer (score 1):

What `private ?bool $is_verified = false;` does is set `false` as the default **PHP** value so it will only work for new insertions.

What you need is to set `false` as the default **SQL** value, to do this you have to change your annotation like this: `#[ORM\Column(options: ['default' => false])]`